# Get height of a view for preferredContentSize

Tags: swift

I'm opening a view controller and as a popover on iPad app. In this popover, I selected to use `preferredContentSize` for its width and height

Currently, I get the hard coded value for both width and hight in a function, and add it here:

```
  vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
  vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
```

In this popover, I only show a label and few lines of text.

The problem is, unlike width, height is not always the same, so I tried to create an `UIView()` and add this label to it with the same width and read its height.

```
   private func calculateHeightForPopover(text: String, Width: Int) -> CGFloat {
  
  let view = UIView()
  view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(Width)).isActive = true
  
  let label = UILabel()
  label.text = text
  
  view.addSubview(label)
  
  view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.topAnchor).isActive = true
  view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
  view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

  view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.heightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

  
  return view.frame.size.height
}
```

but the `view.frame.size.height` is always zero, could anyone help me on that? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The view that created in your function , has only width constraint set and it have doesn't have any other constraints , try setting remaining other constraints and check its height.

Comment: yes because I don't know the height, I want to set the height based on the labels height

Comment: I added one more constraint, still the view,frame.size.height is zero

Comment: try setting top , leading , bottom and width constriants and then check height